# Merge multiple cells into one with some weird critera

Tags: excel, merge, cells

I am stumped on how to attempt this. I have read through some posts
 but here but I'm quite a novice at Excel so not sure what way to go.

I am trying to add metadata to sound effects files. They came with a
 PDF which I've converted in to an xlsx. Normally you get one line for
 each sound file and it's as easy as copying the description column and pasting it into the metadata writing program.
 Problem I have with this CD is that multiple sounds are recorded in
 one file, so the description is in multiple rows.

I need to combine all the descriptions for each file into one cell,
 then remove duplicate words, so I can then paste it into each single
 files description.

B column shows it's the same file by it's leading number.

File 1 = 1-1, 1-2 File 2 = 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, 2-4 File 3 = 3-1, 3-2, 3-3,
 3-4, 3-5 and so on for 990 files

So for File 1 my output would be C2 + D2 + C3 + D3 = AIR, JET STRONG
 STREAM THROUGH ANIMAL, FOOTSTEP ANIMAL FOOTSTEPS IN DIRT: VARIOUS
 MOVEMENTS

Does this seem like it's doable? I tried banging my head on the wall
 but it didn't help ;)

You can see from the first few entries that certain files won't matter
 like File 3 but I really need to have the others have searchable
 metadata.

```
FS01    1-1 AIR, JET STRONG AIR STREAM THROUGH JET
FS01    1-2 ANIMAL, FOOTSTEP ANIMAL FOOTSTEPS IN DIRT: VARIOUS MOVEMENTS
FS01    2-1 APPLAUSE, CROWD SMALL INDOOR CROWD APPLAUSE WITH SLIGHT BUILD
FS01    2-2 APPLAUSE, CROWD SMALL INDOOR CROWD APPLAUSE
FS01    2-3 APPLAUSE, CROWD SMALL INDOOR CROWD APPLAUSE
FS01    2-4 APPLAUSE, CROWD SMALL OUTDOOR CROWD APPLAUSE WITH VOICES
FS01    3-1 APPLAUSE, CROWD SMALL CROWD APPLAUSE
FS01    3-2 APPLAUSE, CROWD SMALL CROWD APPLAUSE
FS01    3-3 APPLAUSE, CROWD SMALL CROWD APPLAUSE
```

[image]

Comment: Wow so that excel example did not post properly!

[IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/34sj6hl.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: You can do the concatenation with functions in the sheet.  Get the file number by in e2 using `=left(B2,find("-",B2,1))` or something close to that and then in cell F2 type `=if(E2=E1,F1&C2&D2,C2&D2)`.  The last step is an equation to find the last concatenation of the sequence.  In cell G2 type `=if(E2=E3,"not last","last")`.  These don't address removing the duplicate keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems to contend with here:

- Files can have variable numbers of "parts"
- Several "parts" within the same file can have the same "description"
- And possibly, the same "description" can occur in different files

One solution to these problems is to

1. Construct a unique list of the files in your data
2. Construct a unique list of the descriptions in your data
3. Construct a table showing for each possible combination of file and
   description whether that combination is present in your data or not
4. Using the table to construct a list for each file of those
   descriptions where the file/description combination exists

An Excel Pivot Table can be used for steps 1-3, above and a bit of twiddling with formulae takes care of 4.

The image below provides an illustration.

[image: Excel screenshot]

There are three elements in the worksheet.

Range `A1:B12` provides the data. There are 11 data points and each point comprises a `File` and a `Desc` (short for 'Description') value. I have deliberately kept both parts short and simple, though there is no reason why they could not be much longer than 1 character each.

Range `D1:I6` is the Pivot Table. (This feature of Excel is extremely powerful and really worth getting to know.) The Pivot Table has been constructed so that its rows correspond to `File` values and its columns to `Desc` values. The Pivot Table shows that the data contains 4 distinct `File` values (1, 2, 3 and 4) and 5 distinct `Desc` values (A, B, C, D and E). (The `File` and `Desc` values showing in the Pivot Table are placed there by Excel.) The entries in the body of the Pivot table count the `File/Desc` combinations that occur in the data and an empty cell indicates that the combination does not occur. So, for example `cell E4` is empty meaning that the combination `2  A` does not occur in the data whilst `cell G5` has a value of 2 signifying that `3 C` occurs twice. If the data is changed the Pivot Table can be refreshed with a single click and will then reflect the newly changed data.

Range `D10:I13` completes the task and is derived from the values in the Pivot Table. There are three formula involved:

Cell D10: `=D3`

Cell E10: `=IF(E3>0,E$2,"")`

Cell F10: `=E10 & IF(AND(LEN(E10)>0,F3>0),"/","") & IF(F3>0,F$2,"")`

`F10` is copied to range `G10:I10` and then `D10:I10` is copied down to `D11:I13`.

The first formula (used in `D10:D13`) simply reproduces the list of `File` values from the Pivot Table. The second formula (used in `E10:E13`) places either the first `Desc` value or the zero-length string `""` according to whether the values in the corresponding area of the Pivot Table are positive or blank. The third formula (used in `F10:I13`) concatenates three strings. The third (rightmost) string is created in a similar way to the second formula using the `Desc` at the top of the corresponding Pivot Table column. The first (leftmost) string is simply the value in the cell to the left. The second (middle) string is either the zero length string or a delimiter. The latter is used only when both the first and third strings are not the zero-length string. I have used the forward slash character `/` as a delimiter to separate successive 'Desc' values but the delimiter could be pretty much anything such as `,` or `*and*` simply by modifying the third formula appropriately.

Each row of the third area effectively performs a cumulative concatenation of the `Desc` values present in the data for the corresponding `File`. The final column, labelled `FullDesc` contains the full list of `Desc` values for each `File`.

Although I have shown the data listed in `File` order this is not necessary for the approach to work. You should be able to use the approach set out here as the basis of your own solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help DMM and bf2020! I used a combination of both your ideas and learnt a lot in the process. I love that you guys came up with a solution so easily, I can now stop banging my head ;)